# Python find and replace strings in files with argument that the string is quoted and not part of bigger string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

i need a solution to the following problem. I want to replace a dynamic string if found in a file but only if there are quotes surrounding the string, either next to it or with max two spaces between, and not be part of bigger string (in python) :

```
ori = 'testing'
rep = 'posting'

file contents:

Line1 This is one line with some words for testing purposes
Line2 this is the seconds "testing" function.
Line3 that is one more " testing" line
Line4 "testing"
Line5 "  testing"
Line6 "testing  "
Line7 "  testing  "
```

Im looking for the following result preferably with regex as simple and efficient way instead of a separate function.

```
Line1 This is one line with some words for testing purposes
Line2 this is the seconds "testing" function.
Line3 that is one more " testing" line
Line4 "posting"
Line5 "  posting"
Line6 "posting  "
Line7 "  posting  "
```

regex magicians may help me at this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `Line1` literally part of the text in your file? Why weren't the top 2 `"testing"` and `" testing"` instances replaced? They're not part of a bigger string and have fewer than 3 spaces in between the quotes and the word. By "string" did you mean "line"? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: `Line1 Line2` is not part of the lines, just markers. The first 2 lines didn't change because `"testing"` is part of a bigger string which is the "whole line".

Comment: OK, are the quotes actually part of the text file? I recommend removing the `Line1` etc and show _exactly_ what's literally in the file. The requirements are vague, but once clarified I can post a solution if you're not completely satisfied with the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression would be a good tool for such a task.
Always take care to express them clearly.
Regular expressions can quickly become puzzling and hard to debug.

```
import re

original = 'testing'
replacement = 'posting'

line1 = 'This is one line with some words for testing purposes'
line2 = 'this is the seconds "testing" function.'
line3 = 'that is one more " testing" line'
line4 = '"testing"'
line5 = '"  testing"'
line6 = '"testing  "'
line7 = '"  testing  "'

lines = [line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7]

starts_with_parentheses = '^"'
ends_with_parentheses = '"$'
one_space = ' {1}'
two_spaces = ' {2}'
none_one_or_two_spaces = '(|{}|{})'.format(one_space, two_spaces)

query = starts_with_parentheses \
        + none_one_or_two_spaces \
        + original \
        + none_one_or_two_spaces \
        + ends_with_parentheses

for line in lines:
    match = re.search(query, line)
    if match:
        line = line.replace(original, replacement)

    print(line)
```

Outputs:

```
This is one line with some words for testing purposes
this is the seconds "testing" function.
that is one more " testing" line
"posting"
"  posting"
"posting  "
"  posting  "
```

Comment: Thank you Max Crous. Wouldn't this work in with `line = re.sub` as well ?

Comment: re.sub does seem like a good fit for the task!
I found it hard to come up with a way to replace 'testing' with 'posting' with re.sub while keeping the surrounding spaces the same, but I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: Thank you again, regex is still black magic for me, i will get there eventually.

Comment: Max Crous, can you do this in a full file readout instead of going line by line which is very slow ?

`with open(filename, "r") as f:
    full_read = f.read()`

So instead of search in lines to search in `full_read`

`match = re.search(query, full_read)
    if match:
        full_read = full_read.replace(original, replacement)`

Comment: So, I think it might be challenging to do the replacement with regular expressions. This is because you will need a different regex for two things, 1. matching the different cases 'testing', '  testing', 'testing ' etc... 2. replacing only the letters of 'testing' and leaving the spaces as they are. It may be possible to express this in a single regex, but I do not know how sorry.