# How to insert corrections to a file using regex (Python)

Tags: python, file-writing, python-re

I'm trying to correct certain entries in a data set (~30MB). Specifically a csv file with a text column and a pos/neg column. Some of the text fields are missing wrapping quotation marks so I'd like to insert these manually.
This is the code I've written to do so:

```
add_quotes = re.compile(r'^(([^"]|"")(.*)([^"]|"")),(pos|neg)$')
with open(<path-to-csv>, 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
s = re.sub(add_quotes, r'"\1",\5', s)
with open(<path-to-same-csv>, 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

The problem I'm facing is that after running this code, the regex I used to find the quotes still matches some entries in the file.
So far I've tried:
1. Opening the file as `'r+'` and calling `f.seek(0)` before writing, instead of first `'r'` and then `'w'`.
2. Writing to a different file.
3. Opening and editing the file in bytes format instead of text (i.e. `'r+b'` / `'wb'`).
All of these run smoothly but achieve the same result.

Notes:

- calling `add_quotes.findall(s)` after the substitution returns an empty list, so the string is changed but somehow the changes aren't written to the file
- the same code on a smaller file with just 1 example works

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

I've tried to use this on a file with 3 entries and it doesn't work, so I'm suspecting the problem is with the regex and has nothing to do with file size.

Comment: 30MB does not sound that large, in the sense that it can easily fit in your computer's memory. If your program runs without any exceptions it may not be a size issue.

Comment: The .* is a greedy match - perhaps try a non-greedy match or break on commas?

Comment: @MaxCrous The file does fit into my memory. Would removing the word _large_ help clarify the question?

Comment: I'm not sure that will chance will clarify the issue a lot. I think part of the challenge here is that the regex is hard to parse (for humans), which makes it difficult for you to do decide whether it is the correct regex. That is, whether it matches the patterns you want to match. 
An alternative approach would be to read in the file with the python csv module, and manipulate the string manually. I will write an answer with example code now.

Comment: In the meantime, take a look at this answer on regexes, and how to build them up in a modular way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021636/python-find-and-replace-strings-in-files-with-argument-that-the-string-is-quoted/59021863#59021863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the flag `re.MULTILINE` solved the problem:

`add_quotes = re.compile(r'^(([^"]|"")(.*)([^"]|"")),(pos|neg)$', re.MULTILINE)`

The `^` operator probably didn't match any but the first line without this flag and the `$` probably matched only the last, so every entry in between wasn't matched.

My confusion was because searching this expression in the file through an editor returned matches even after I thought I filtered them out.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex for matching and substituting a pattern throughout a file will take away some of your control over your code. By iterating over the rows, and applying changes to strings yourself, you will have more opportunities to debug and test what's wrong.

```
import csv 

with open('output_file_name_here.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    with open('input_file_name_here.csv') as input_file:

        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)

        for row in reader:
            (col1, col2) = row

            if col1[0] != '"':
                col1 = '"' + col1

            if col[-1] != '"': 
                col1 = col1 + '"'

            writer.writerow([col1, col2])
```